# How to fix ERR_SSL_PROTOCOL_ERROR?

Tags: go, https

I recently deployed my frontend to my godaddy server + domain. I made a container out of my backend that is written in Go. All the backend does is provide an api endpoint that sends an email to me. My frontend accesses it in this component (it's a React app):

```
import React, { SetStateAction, useState } from "react";
import Input from "./Input";
import Button from "./Button";
import { motion, easeIn } from "framer-motion";

export interface email {
  senderEmail: string;
  senderName: string;
  message: string;
}

type responseProps = {
  response: React.Dispatch<SetStateAction<boolean | null>>;
};
const Form = (props: responseProps) => {
  const [data, setData] = useState<email>({
    senderEmail: "",
    senderName: "",
    message: "",
  });

  const sendEmail = async () => {
    const url = "https://ip:8080/email/";
    try {
      const response = await fetch(url, {
        method: "POST",
        headers: {
          "Content-Type": "application/json",
        },
        body: JSON.stringify(data),
      });
      if (response.ok) {
        props.response(true);
      } else {
        props.response(false);
      }
    } catch (error) {
      props.response(false);
      console.error(error);
    }
  };

  return (
    <motion.div
      initial={{ opacity: 0, x: -200 }}
      whileInView={{ opacity: 1, x: 0 }}
      transition={{ duration: 0.6, ease: easeIn }}
      viewport={{ once: true }}
      className="w-full m-auto flex flex-col gap-6 "
    >
      <div className="flex  w-full gap-3 ">
        <Input onChange={setData} type="text" text="Name" />
        <Input onChange={setData} type="email" text="Email" />
      </div>
      <Input onChange={setData} type="text" text="Message" msg={true} />
      <div className="w-full flex ">
        <Button onClick={sendEmail} />
      </div>
    </motion.div>
  );
};

export default Form;
```

and here is the backend:

```
package main

import (
    "encoding/json"
    "fmt"
    "log"
    "net/http"
    "net/smtp"

    "github.com/rs/cors"
)

type EmailRequest struct {
    SenderEmail string `json:"senderEmail"`
    SenderName  string `json:"senderName"`
    Message     string `json:"message"`
}

func SendEmail(emailReq EmailRequest) error {
    auth := smtp.PlainAuth("", "myemail@gmail.com", "swnhmrwnqfrsrdqo", "smtp.gmail.com")
    msg := fmt.Sprintf("From:\r%s\nName:\r%s\nMessage:\r%s\n", emailReq.SenderEmail, emailReq.SenderName, emailReq.Message)
    err := smtp.SendMail("smtp.gmail.com:587", auth, "myemail@gmail.com", []string{"myemail@gmail.com"}, []byte(msg))
    if err != nil {
        return err
    }
    return nil
}

func Email(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
    if r.Method != "POST" {
        w.Header().Set("Allow", "POST")
        w.WriteHeader(405)
        w.Write([]byte("Method Not Allowed"))
        return
    }
    var emailReq EmailRequest
    if err := json.NewDecoder(r.Body).Decode(&emailReq); err != nil {
        w.WriteHeader(http.StatusBadRequest)
        w.Write([]byte("Bad Request"))
        return
    }
    if err := SendEmail(emailReq); err != nil {
        w.WriteHeader(http.StatusInternalServerError)
        w.Write([]byte("Internal Server Error"))
        log.Printf("Error with the SendEmail func execution: %v", err)
        return
    }
    w.WriteHeader(http.StatusOK)
    w.Write([]byte("Email sent successfully"))
}

func main() {
    c := cors.New(cors.Options{
        AllowedOrigins:   []string{"https://cihanbatasul.com"},
        AllowedMethods:   []string{http.MethodPost},
        AllowCredentials: true,
    })
    mux := http.NewServeMux()
    mux.HandleFunc("/email/", Email)

    handler := c.Handler(mux)

    log.Print("Listening on port :8080")
    err := http.ListenAndServe(":8080", handler)
    log.Fatal(err)
}
```

But when I make the call I get the following errors:
[image]

Thank you in advance!

Comment: *"http.ListenAndServe(...)"* - this is starting a plain HTTP server, not HTTPS. Since you attempt to use it with secure `https://` instead of plain `http://` you get this error.

Comment: Thank you for your help. I'm gonna make it a https server!